# *ngFor won't Iterate through array data

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-httpclient

So I am having trouble Iterating through an array. Angular does not show all the data. It only shows the data at the specific location.

**This is the Component**

```
    export class LiveComponent implements OnInit {
    allData: any = null;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {
    }
    ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('http://api.redacted_for_privacy').subscribe(data => {this.allData = [data];});
    }
    }
```

**This is the HTML**

```
    <mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let data of allData">{{data.city[1].section[2].street}}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
```

See the data comes back from the API as an object so i had to place that object inside of an array for angular to be able to Iterate.

Inside that object that's returned from the API is also arrays and the only way i could get access to the data is to for directly to the index **[#]** `city[1].section[2]` . The problem with the code is obvious. It is explicitly stating the index so there won't be Iteration.

I would like to Iterate through the data. How do i fix this code ?

I am expecting the data to come back as

```
      <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let data of allData">Street 1</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let data of allData">Street 2</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let data of allData">Street 3</mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
```

But the data comes back as

```
      <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let data of allData">Street 1</mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
```

**This is the Data Structure**

```
{
"value": "data"
"state":{
"code": "value"
"history": {
"key": "value"}
},
"city": [{
        "key": "home",
        "key": {
            "key": "value",
            "key": "value",
            "key": "value"
        },
        "section": [{
            "street": "Value Street",
        }, {
            "street": "Value Street",
        }]
} 
}
```

Comment: if the data is an `object` and you place it in an array, you get an array with a single element. So what sense does a `*ngFor` make? Please post an example how `data` really looks like (you can anonymize the contents, but post the *original structure*!)

Comment: here is a fiddle . [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xt3dLvz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

So you actually have an object which has some keyes with arrays of objects as value, that in turn have some keyes that have arrays as values, or even arrays of objects as values. There's no point then in trying to iterate over top-level data, since it's just a single object. However, you *can* iterate over this object's fields that have arrays as values, and depending on the depth of these nested objects with arrays, you just need to put ngFor inside ngFor.

So if your data object actually is like this:

```
{
   city: [ // array
      // containing any number of objects having 'section' as key:
      {
         section: [ // array
             // containing any number of objects having 'street' as key:
             {
                 street: 'Street 1'
             }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and you want to display only `street` values, you can do it like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let city of data1.city">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let section of city.section">
        <p>{{ section.street }}</p>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

(or any html tags/elements you're up for).

If your data structure is like this:

```
{
   city: [ // array
      // containing any number of objects having 'section' as key:
      {
         section: [ // array
             // containing any number of strings as street names:
             'Street 1', 'Street 2'
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

you can go with:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let city of data2.city">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let street of city.section">
        <p>{{ street }}</p>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

In both cases, regardless of the `data` structure, you don't iterate over `data` itself, and with this approach in template you can use top-level iteration (first line of ngFor) to display some top-level data about the list of streets that comes next, or just use it for css styling (change ng-template to some real DOM element, though).

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ovlug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: This works, but it gives a whole different issue. If I am to use `| slice:0:10;` the value **street** now becomes unusable with an error message **Object is of type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2571)**

Comment: You definitely need to share at least the barebone structure of your data and what exactly are you trying to achieve,

Comment: hey. Here is a fiddle . [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xt3dLvz/1/)